# WebDriver (Ruby): How to avoid "Compound class names not permitted" error with parent and child element (nested) in one query

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In the case of a child / nested element such as this

```
<span class="target-identification">
   <h2 class="light collapsed card-title">
</span>
```

how would one target the child / nested element in one query without triggering the

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
```

error?

Answer (score 1):

If one wishes to target a child element then this is one way to do so

```
driver.find_element(css:'.parent-class-name .desired-child-class-name')
```

**E.g.** if this is the HTML

```
<span class="target-identification">
   <h2 class="light collapsed card-title">
</span>
```

then the command would be

```
driver.find_element(css:'.target-identification .card-title')
```

---

Alternatively, a two-step option, where one searches inside the outer / parent element is as follows:

```
parent_element  = driver.find_element(class: 'target-identification')
desired_element = parent_element.find_element(class: 'card-title')
```

Comment: I could not find an answer as direct as this so I have shared this tip.